# Rudin Theorem 7.11

Tags: real-analysis

There is a part in the proof which I see as blatantly wrong.

In his proof, he defines $A_n=\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t)$.

Then, he states that $|A_n-A_m|<\varepsilon$ since $f_n$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of functions.

Here is where the problem comes. He says that since the sequence is Cauchy, it must converge. That doesn't seem to be true to me, at least in non-compact spaces.

Is there something I do not understand or did Rudin make a mistake? I think he has the same error in the previous theorem as he refers to theorem 3.11 (b) which basically states that the set must be compact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cauchy sequences converge in a *complete* space, it does not have to be compact. $A_k$ are numbers, I guess, $A_k\in\mathbb{C}$, so it is ok.

Comment: How is that correct? What if $A_k\in\mathbb{Q}$? $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete as far as I know. I said compact because that's what came to mind as an example of a complete space, but I know a non-compact space can be complete. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If $(A_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb Q$ , it converge in $ \Bbb R$, so there is no problem... Is that a problem that the limit of $A_n$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Rudin defines the functions on a set $E$ in a metric space, presumable a subset of $\mathbb C$. There is nothing wrong with the proof.

Comment: The functions are assumed to be complex valued in that chapter, so there is no problem.

Comment: Yeah, is $\mathbb{Q}$ not a metric space? I'm not getting the point to be honest, unless @Nitin is answering to the above question.

zhw. being complex valued doesn't mean they can't be restricted to the rationals and $E$ being a set of only rational numbers, right?

Comment: Even if the $A_n$ are rational, every Cauchy sequence of rationals converges when taken as a subset of the reals.

Comment: @HasanSaad What functions do you have in the Theorem 7.11? Are they really $\mathbb{Q}$-valued?

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. He didn't say it had to converge in $E$ and to be honest, I missed that he said they were complex-valued or something. Thanks mates. Anyone post an answer so I accept it or should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the key ingredient here is *completeness* of $\Bbb R$. Rudin deduces that for all $n$ and $m$ sufficiently large that
$$
|A_n - A_m| \le \epsilon,
$$
so that $\{A_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, and therefore converges by the completeness of $\Bbb R$.

In the earlier theorem you reference, Theorem 7.8, we have the same that the point $x$ is fixed and the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$, which is a sequence of real numbers, is Cauchy. Again, by completeness, this sequence converges to some real number.

Compactness is not the important thing here, it's really the fact that the real numbers form a *complete metric space* that allows us to recognize Cauchy sequences as convergent sequences.

Comment: In fact "completeness of $\;\Bbb C\;$", as the function of that chapter are assumed to be complex valued from the very beginning.