# Doubt in theorem 7.11 of Baby Rudin regarding completeness.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

[Rudin Theorem 7.11](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391133/rudin-theorem-7-11)

In the proof of Theorem 7.11 of Baby Rudin, it is mentioned the sequence $\{ A_n \} _n$ is convergent because it is Cauchy. I didn't initially understand this as $E$, the domain of the functions was not declared to be complete.
The above answer in the link tells that since they belong to $\mathbb{R}$, hence they are convergent iff Cauchy as $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

But, the limit of a function is defined to be an element belonging to the range of the function. Here we aren't told whether the range is $\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone give me the reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: Wer are said at the very beginning of chapter 7 that the functions that are going to be discussed are complex valued...so there is no problem with completeness.

Comment: Never noticed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong when you assume that the limit of a function is defined to be an element belonging to the range of the function. For instance, the range of the exponential function is $(0,\infty)$, but $\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x=0\notin(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Definition 4.1 of Rudin states this. I can share a picture

Comment: The definition is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3094615/446262). It only claims that the limit belongs to the **codomain** of $f$, not to its **range**.

Comment: Yes sir, but It isn't stated that the codomain is $\mathbb R$ ? I don't understand sir can you please help?

Comment: The first sentence of chapter 7 begins with the words “In the present chapter we confine our attention to complex-valued functions”. And $\Bbb C$ *is* complete.